# How check on_message if message has emoji for discord py?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm fairly new at using python and I'm trying to code a discord bot with basics functions, and I want for one of them to be that after someone uses a prefix if they post an emoji that the bot replies with the url of the emoji, but I have trouble trying to make it work. I don't know how to use on_message to check if a message contains an emoji. Could anyone help me? Thanks.

```
#if message.content[0] == "!" and message.content[1:4] == " <:":
            #print(message.content[4:-1])
            #emoji_name = ""
            #for i in str(message.content[4:-1]):
                #if i != ":":
                    #emoji_name += i
                #if i == ":":
                    #print(emoji_name)
                    #break
            #await client.send_message(message.channel, get(client.get_all_emojis(), name=emoji_name).url)
```

Comment: I made this bad code which works if done correctly, but if not fires plenty of errors. Look at above post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Discord custom emoji has a form of `<:name:id>`. So if you use `re`, Python regex library, you can find all the custom emojis in the given message.

```
import re
import discord

@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    custom_emojis = re.findall(r'<:\w*:\d*>', msg.content)
    custom_emojis = [int(e.split(':')[1].replace('>', '')) for e in custom_emojis]
    custom_emojis = [discord.utils.get(client.get_all_emojis(), id=e) for e in custom_emojis]
    # From now, `custom_emojis` is `list` of `discord.Emoji` that `msg` contains.
```

I didn't test this code now, but i used this method before and found it worked. So please give me feedback if this doesn't work, then i will find if i mis-typed.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I didn't know about re, but it doesn't work. I got an error on the first line giving me : TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: It also doesn't work for custom emojis not from the server.

Comment: sorry i didn't use `msg.content` instead of `msg`. Because the second argument of `re.findall` is `str`, you should change `msg` to `msg.content`.