# How do you identify emojis through a user's message?

Tags: python, discord.py, emoji

I'm collecting a user's message with the client.wait_for command, and I wanted to know a way that I can identify if the message is an emoji (either default or custom). I've attempted to use guild.fetch_emoji and client.get_emoji in order to detect whether it is a proper emoji. Will I have to put the message through multiple functions?

```
while continue_function:
    user_msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel)
    emoji = self.bot.get_emoji(user_msg.content)
    emoji2 = ctx.guild.fetch_emoji(user_msg.content)
    print(emoji,emoji2)
```

Comment: `self.bot.get_emoji()` doesn't take a string. It takes a discord ID (emoji ID) which it will then search for through the bot's cache.  Same thing with `guild.fetch_emoji`

Comment: Does this help to answer your question? [How check on\_message if message has emoji for discord py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54859876/how-check-on-message-if-message-has-emoji-for-discord-py)

Answer (score 2):

As @12944qwerty said, you cannot use a string to fetch the the emoji. However if you want to catch messages that just contain an emoji, for exemple "", as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36216665/find-there-is-an-emoji-in-a-string-in-python3) you can use `from emoji import UNICODE_EMOJI` to have a list of all unicode emojis, then you can find if there is an emoji in your message by using this function

```
def is_emoji(content):
    for emoji in UNICODE_EMOJI:
        if content == emoji:
            return True
    return False
```

You can modify this function if you want to check for multiple emojis or just checking if `emoji in content` instead, it depends on waht you need.

This won't work for custom emojis, or emojis that do not exist for unicode. For custom emoji you can use this RegEx `<:\w+:(\d+)>` to get the id of the custom emoji that you'll be able to use with `get_emoji()` or `fetch_emoji()`. Use [this resource](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for more information about RegEx in python